# How to refresh list page and not loose focus in the grid?

Tags: axapta

I am opening detail of an item in list page grid. There may be some changes so after detail is close() I and refreshing the list page datasource.

I am acessing the list page datasource from arguments

```
FormDataSource   callerDataSource;
callerDataSource = element.args().record().dataSource();
```

But I can obtain one of following results.

1) I reread() the current record.

```
callerDataSource.reread();
```

The data in grid are changed but the form parts do not refresh.

2) I research(true) the datasource

```
callerDataSource.research(true);
```

I try even [this](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/dynamicsnavax/archive/2013/07/20/refresh-caller-form-ax-2012.aspx) version of research

```
callerDataSource.reread();       
callerDataSource.rereadReferenceDataSources();            
callerDataSource.research(true);
```

but I lost focus in grid.

3) I call task F5 by

```
#Task
Element.args().caller().task(#taskF5);
```

but the focus is lost here too.

I would like to have new data in grid and in form part but do not lost focus in grid. (Refreshing of only selected record and info parts which depends on it will be enough.)

The table has primary index selected. It is recid (which is not shown in grid).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind I find [this blog](http://devexpp.blogspot.com.br/2012/02/refresh-datasource-and-retain-position.html)

My solution is use the position

```
FormDataSource   callerDataSource;
int position;
callerDataSource = element.args().record().dataSource();    

position = callerDataSource.getPosition();
callerDataSource.reread();               
callerDataSource.research(true);
callerDataSource.setPosition(position);
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the `reread()` if you are using `research()`, as explained [here](http://kashperuk.blogspot.com.es/2010/03/tutorial-reread-refresh-research.html) or [in the update of the blog post you linked](http://devexpp.blogspot.com.br/2013/03/how-to-effectively-refresh-data-on.html)